# Material UI: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'up')

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this component and I'm trying to use "breakpoint", but I get this error, Note that I am using the latest version of the material:

```
Property 'breakpoints' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'
```

file.tsx:

```
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { FC } from "react";
import ResponsiveConstants from "./ResponsiveConstants";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up(ResponsiveConstants.mobileBreakpoint)]: {
      minHeight: 600,
    },
  },
}));

const ResponsiveContainerGrid: FC = ({  children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid
        className={classes.root}
        container
        direction="row"
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
      >
        {children}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResponsiveContainerGrid;
```

Then I tried to modify the code and used the following instruction:

```
import { Theme } from '@mui/system';
```

And the code became:

```
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { FC } from "react";
import ResponsiveConstants from "./ResponsiveConstants";
import { Theme } from '@mui/system';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up(ResponsiveConstants.mobileBreakpoint)]: {
      minHeight: 600,
    },
  },
}));

const ResponsiveContainerGrid: FC = ({  children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid
        className={classes.root}
        container
        direction="row"
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
      >
        {children}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResponsiveContainerGrid;
```

But I had a problem, which is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'up')
```

How can I solve the first or second problem?

Comment: The problem is solved?

Comment: no, it's not solved

Answer (score -1):

Delete the node_modules folder, then clear the NPM and/or Yarn cache by running:

1. **For NPM do**: npm cache clean --force
2. **For Yarn do**: yarn cache clean --force
3. Next, reinstall all your packages with either npm or yarn. This
   resolved my problem